# ArcGIS 10.5 Python toolbox problem SelectLayerByAttributeERROR 000358: Invalid expression Failed to execute

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, python-toolbox, error-000358

I am trying to create a .pyt that find and select an object in an specific layer but I have a problem.
I'm working on the Desktop version 10.5 and actually the code is this one:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    Cabina = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Cabina",
        name="cab",
        datatype="string",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

    params = [Cabina]
    return params

def isLicensed(self):
    """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
    return True

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    return

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"ESERCIZIO\ELE_ESER_Cab")
    exp = "'" + str(Cabina) + "'"
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view= lyr, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause= "COD_CABINA LIKE" + exp)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    return 
    `
```

the problem is that continue to appear this error message: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression Failed to execute. (I'm working in an Oracle environment)
Actually I tried to put a value such as exp = 'A0001' and the script work well.
I read almost everything but seems like nothing works. I tried to find some documentation about how to use custom input and SQL but I did not find so much.

Comment: Try: `sql = "{0} LIKE '{1}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=lyr, field='COD_CABINA'), Cabina)` and then `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view= lyr, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause=sql)`

Comment: I tried but does not work, appear the ERROR 000358. I tried to run the script on the Python idle and there works perfectly but if i run the Toolbox something go wrong. Actually the results of .format is '"COD_CABINA" LIKE \'A540\''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code to this, it should work:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    Cabina = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Cabina",
        name="cab",
        datatype="string",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

    params = [Cabina]
    return params

def isLicensed(self):
    """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
    return True

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    return

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"ESERCIZIO\ELE_ESER_Cab")
    Cabina = parameters[0].valueAsText
    exp = "{} LIKE '{}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=lyr, field='COD_CABINA'), Cabina)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view= lyr, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause= "COD_CABINA LIKE" + exp)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    return
```

The execute method doesn't know anything about the parameter you defined as Cabina, you need to define this again within this function.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `Cabina` as a Parameter then treating it as if it is a string variable when you build your expression. You need to [access the Parameters value](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/accessing-parameters-within-a-python-toolbox.htm) and build the sql expression from that.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone it is work! now i will go deeper in the parameter Value!